# python create temporary file, what is the interest?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I've recently started working with python. In another topic, I read that someone had to create temporary files, has he had to create file (also in python).

So my question is, what is the interest of working with temp files ?

To me it would be, not to have too many (unneeded files, that can be removed later).

In my project, I have a main file

> **main.dat**

In which I extract 2 blocks,

> **main_first_block.dat**
>
> **main_second_block.dat**

And then I combine **`main_second_block.dat`** and **`main_second_block.dat`**

> **final_file.dat**

So it makes a total of **4 files**.

And at the end, I dont need **`main_first_block.dat`** and **`main_second_block.dat`** anymore.

I only need to keep **`main_file.dat`** and **`final_file.dat`**

So my question is, should I create tmp files, or delete the unneeded files at the end of my script ?

Thanks guys for your enlightenment ;)

Comment: Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile): _The file is created using mkstemp(). It will be destroyed as soon as it is closed_

Answer (score 2):

There is not really that much a difference in lines of code. 
Yet, tmp files indicate that they are not made to stay. Therefore they bring more clarity to your code.

When using tmp files make sure to avoid the mktemp()-function 
as it is highly vulnerable to attacks.

Hope I could help in some way.